# Difference between 'connection reset' exception and -1 return value on read when a Java socket is closed

Tags: java, sockets, io

I have a Java socket that connects to a server and receives a sequence of buffers from that server. The transfer stops when the server closes the connection, i.e. closes the accepting socket on its side.

Most of the time, when the servers closes the connection, the client gets a -1 return code on the read method on the `InputStream` associated with the socket:

```
Socket sSocket   = new Socket(ServerAddress ,acceptorPort);
InputStream  isr = sSocket.getInputStream();

byte[] buf              = new byte[3200];
int    rr               = 1;

while (rr != -1) {
    try {
        rr     = isr.read(buffer);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        break;
    }
}
```

But sometimes the `read` raises a `java.net.SocketException: Connection reset`.
In that case, I have the following stack trace:

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:127)
at com.testing.sockets.SimpleReadTest.main(SimpleReadTest.java:149)
```

What is the difference and why?

Answer (score 0):

The difference according to [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read()) is this:

- -1 if there is no more data because the end of the stream has been reached.
- java.net.IOException - if an I/O error occurs.

`java.net.SocketException` extends `java.io.IOException`, so it is caught by your `catch`-block.

Comment: 'Connection reset' is not caused by creating the input stream, a closed socket, a non-connected socket, nor by `shutdownInput()`. Nor is it implementation-dependent.